# Items in WinForms ComboBox not updating when DataSource values change

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox bound to a List via a DataSource. For some reason, when the datasource items change, the items in the combo box don't seem to automatically update.   I can see in the debugger the datasource contains the correct items.

There are lots of answers on StackOverflow about this, but most are either unanswered, don't work for me, or require changing from using Lists to BindingLists which I cannot do this instance due to the volume of code which uses methods BindingLists don't have.

Surely there must be a **simple** way of just telling the ComboBox to refresh it's items?  I can't believe this doesn't exist.  I already have an event which fires when the Combo needs to be updated, but my code to update the values has no effect.

Combo declaration:

```
    this.devicePortCombo.DataBindings.Add(
             new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", 
               this.deviceManagementModelBindingSource, "SelectedDevice", true,
               DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    this.devicePortCombo.DataSource = this.availableDevicesBindingSource;
```

Code to update the combobox:

```
private void Instance_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "AvailableDevices")
    {
        // Rebind dropdown when available device list changes.
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            devicePortCombo.DataSource = AvailableDevicesList;
            devicePortCombo.DataBindings[0].ReadValue();
            devicePortCombo.Refresh();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using a BindingSource did you try BindingSource.ResetBindings() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When I've had this issue before I've had to set the datasource to nothing, then re-add it.

Comment: But that can cause any selected value to become unset, which is different to how it works if a BindingList is used.

Answer (score 3):

You are not binding the DataGridview's `DataSource` to same BindingSource object in your case `this.availableDevicesBindingSource` which bound first time. but  later you are binding to different object `AvailableDevicesList`. again you are using another binding source for `SelectedValue` i.e `this.deviceManagementModelBindingSource`.

use one `BindingSource` only, may solve your issue

Comment: Thanks  - but my question was from 2 years ago :)

Comment: There were no answers for your question, someone else can find help from your question.